# Get the range that a cell points to

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to come up with a VBA formula that will take a cell, and return the range that that cell references. This is what I have so far:

```
Function GetAddressCellPointsTo(ByRef src As Range) As Range
    On Error GoTo InvalidSrc
    referenceText = Replace(src.Formula, "=", "")
    Set GetAddressCellPointsTo = Range(referenceText)
    Exit Function
InvalidSrc:
    err.Raise 1, "GetAddressCellPointsTo", "The formula of the source cell must be a single reference to another cell or range."
End Function
```

The problem is that I know this won't work reliably if the cell doesn't contain a valid range, or if the reference isn't fully qualified in the source cell (i.e. `=A1` vs `=Sheet1!A1`), or maybe if the cell is pointing to a named range.

What I'd like to do is reliably pull the reference to a range if that's what the cell is pointing to, otherwise return an error message.

Comment: ARe you sure this doesn't work? Did you test it? As far as I can tell, it does exactly what it is supposed to do. What does it fail to do?

Comment: In general case this approach will not work. The cell may contain a reference to another cell in a form, for example, "=OFFSET(INDIRECT($D438),E418+E2,1)". I ended up parsing the .Formula looking for this special case (which was relevant to my application), but I would love to see if there is a generic solution

Comment: @nsg Yeah, I don't need such a general solution, although in that case I imagine there's something complicated you can do to ask excel about the precedents of that cell (like when clicking 'trace precedents') to figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slight modification that I believe fits your requirement:

```
Function GetAddressCellPointsTo(ByRef src As Range) As Range
    referenceText = Replace(src.Formula, "=", "")
    On Error Resume Next
    'Return err.Number 1004 if referenceText not on current sheet
    Set GetAddressCellPointsTo = src.Parent.Range(referenceText)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo InvalidSrc
        Set GetAddressCellPointsTo = Range(referenceText)
    End If
    Exit Function
InvalidSrc:
    Err.Raise 1, "GetAddressCellPointsTo", "The formula of the source cell must be a single reference to another cell or range."
End Function
```

This will first find the reference on the sheet that src is on. If that fails, which it does for any reference not on the sheet, it will try without specifying the sheet.

Comment: Yeah I think this nails my main concern. I'm not really worried about cases where `indirect` is used and such. I was a little worried about using named ranges, especially when the current active sheet (default used for `Range`) isn't the same as the scr sheet, and if it happens to have a the same name scoped to each sheet. Checking first for the validity of the reference on `src.Parent.Range` is the fix.